Solving the system $x + \frac{3x-y}{x^2+y^2} = 3$, $y + \frac{3y-x}{x^2+y^2} = 0$
Given the system
$$\begin{equation}
x + \frac{3x-y}{x^2+y^2} = 3 \\
y + \frac{3y-x}{x^2+y^2} = 0
\end{equation}$$
My first instinct was to solve the second equation as a quadratic equation in $x$ and put the resulting solution in the first equation - however, the algebra was too messy.
My second idea was to substitute the $x=r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta $, motivated by the $x^2 + y^2$ in the denominator. This gives us two quadratics $r$, taking their common solution gives us $$r = \frac{\cos 2 \theta}{3 \sin \theta}$$
and $$r^2 = \frac{\cos \theta - 3 \sin \theta}{\sin \theta} $$
Equating, we get the equation $$4 \cos^4 \theta - 13 \cos^2 \theta + 10 = 3 \sin \theta \cos \theta $$
which I believe could be solved by squaring, but again I believe that polynomials might get too messy to solve (octic equations are not fun).
I am completely out of ideas and so are my teachers; I can't use anything super advanced because this is supposed to be solved using only my syllabus (Indian Grade 10 syllabus). Of course, though, I would appreciate any method to solve this question.
EDIT: This question came in a mock test at a coaching of mine, but they haven't given us the solutions, only an answer key. The solutions are $(2,1)$ and $(1,-1)$
Thanks in advance!

From here, you can either attempt to solve this system for r and θ, or alternatively, apply some known methods for solving such nonlinear systems of equations, perhaps numerically or by making certain assumptions (like trying specific values for
r and
θ).

I can't do numerical methods, as this question came in a mock test and so I need an analytical solution. The answer key says the solutions are $(2,1)$ and $(1,-1)$. As for solving for $r$ and $\theta$, that is exactly where I am stuck because solving for $\cos \theta$ or $\sin \theta$ would involve an octic polynomial.

doing $x=1$ and $y=-1$ does not fit with the second equation ?

The problem is indeed written correctly..I didn't try putting them. I'll tell my coaching that the solutions are wrong.

Hint: Consider instead the set of equations
$$\begin{cases}x + \dfrac{3x-y}{z} &= 3\\ y + \dfrac{3y-x}{z} &= 0\\ x^2 + y^2 &= z \end{cases}$$
Use $z$ as a parameter in the first two equations (which are linear in $x$ and $y$) to solve $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$. Note that $z\neq 0$, so when you substitute $x$ and $y$ in the last equation, you'll be able to simplify a few things and obtain a cuartic equation on $z$. Discard any solution that makes $z$ a negative number.

I'll try, thanks for the suggestion!

I got $x = \frac{3z(z+3)}{z^2 + 6z +8}$ and $y = \frac{3z}{z^2 + 6z +8}$. I put it in and got the equation $$\frac{(z+3)^2 + 1}{(z+2)^2 (z+4)^2} = \frac{1}{9}$$ which gives me $$z = \sqrt{\frac{11 + 3 \sqrt{17}}{2}} - 3$$

@Kraken The equation you got when substituting $x$ and $y$ in the last equation is missing a $z$. You should get $$z\dfrac{(z+3)^2 + 1}{(z+2)^2(z+4)^2} = \dfrac{1}{9}.$$

I see, makes sense why I was getting real solutions. Thanks @Darth Geek!

We can rewrite this as $f=g=0$ with the two polynomials
$$
f=x^3 - 3x^2 + xy^2 + 3x - 3y^2 - y,\quad g=x^2y - x + y^3 + 3y
$$
Every common solution $x$ satisfies $res(f,g)=0$, where
$$
res(f,g)=x(2x^4 - 12x^3 + 69x^2 - 144x + 112)=0.
$$
For $x=0$ we obtain $3y=-1$ and $y^2=-3$, a contradiction. So we obtain four complex solutions (all not real).

I see, I forgot the resultant exists. Useful for solving systems; but this is a concept of linear algebra as it needs me to evaluate a determinant. Thanks for the solution, +1! Also the resultant is never 0 for a real x; does that mean no solution over the real numbers exist?

Yes, there is no real solution. There is a typo, I suppose.

Continuing from your idea by trigonometric form, we have
$$4 \cos^4 \theta - 13 \cos^2 \theta + 10 = 3 \sin \theta \cos \theta \iff (\cos(2\theta)-3)(2\cos(2\theta)-3)=3\sin(2\theta)$$
and by tangent half-angle formula by $t=\tan \theta$ we obtain the equivalent equation
$$f(t)=10 t^4 - 3 t^3 + 7 t^2 - 3 t + 1=0$$
which is impossible since $f'(t)=0$ has exactly one root which is a positive minimum for $f(t)$.

As an alternative, to prove the latter result, we can complete the squares to obtain
$$10 t^4 - 3 t^3 + 7 t^2 - 3 t + 1=\frac{t^2}{40}\left(20t-3\right)^2+\frac1{10840}\left(271 t - 60\right)^2 + \frac{181}{271}>0$$

Could you explain how went from $( \cos (2 \theta) - 3)( 2\cos (2 \theta) - 3) = 3 \sin (2 \theta)$ to $f(t)$? I couldn't exactly understand which form of the the tangent half-angle formula you used.

Those are very useful formulas, $\cos (2x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin (2x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ with $t=\tan x$. Take a look to the link.

I think your first idea is a very good way to solve the question.

Wait, those are called tangent half-angle formulas? I always called them the sine and cosine double-angle formulae. Well, that resolves it. Good solution, +1!

Yes the have different names, they are useful to transform trigonometric equations (or inequalities) into rational or polynomial expressions.

Too long for comment:

Let $u=x+y, \ v=x-y$, $x=\frac{u+v}{2}, \ y =\frac{u-v}{2}, \ x^2+y^2=\frac{u^2+v^2}{2}$
$$x+\frac{3x-y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{u+v}{2}+\frac{2u+4v}{u^2+v^2}=3$$
$$y+\frac{3y-x}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{u-v}{2}+\frac{2u-4v}{u^2+v^2}=0$$
....
$$u+\frac{4u}{u^2+v^2}=3$$
$$v+\frac{8v}{u^2+v^2}=3$$
$$\frac{u}{3-u}=\frac{v}{2(3-v)}$$
$$u=\frac{3v}{6-v}$$
$$u^2+v^2=\frac{v}{6-2v}$$

I think this could be used, but I don't know. I haven't tried this

I've also tried this kind of transformation but without any good result. How dou you conclude from here?

@user I couldn't. I posted this because I felt that this path might lead to something but I wasn't able to proceed from here.
